# Layout visibility default value with data binding is not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

I am trying to set the layout visibility with data binding. While the data is being loaded from the database, the default visibility which I set in XML is not working.  Here is the layout file

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/error_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="@{homeViewModel.comfortErrorVisibility, default=invisible}"/>
```

The view model is like this

```
public class HomeViewModel extends BaseObservable {

    private ObservableField<String> comfortErrorMessage = new ObservableField<>();

    public HomeViewModel(){
        validateSpace();
    }


    @Bindable
    public int getComfortErrorVisibility(){
        // change the visibility based on error message
        return TextUtils.isEmpty(comfortErrorMessage.get()) ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE;
    }

    private void validateSpace(){
        //some business logic to set the comfrotErrorMessage
    }
}
```

Am I missing anything here? By default, I want to set the visibility as invisible for error layout. But its shown by default.

Answer (score 0):

use `visibility = invisible` or gone:

```
        <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/error_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

and then change the visibilty programmatically where you need it

```
 if(TextUtils.isEmpty(some_error))
  {  
 findViewbyId(R.id.error_layout).setVisibilty(View.VISIBILE)}
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, I am using data binding concept to update the UI. This is not feasible for that.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, `default` is just for the preview on Android studio and won't do anything in runtime. Can't find the official documentation anymore, but there are quite a few SO Posts about it.

From what I can tell, when you set the binding the data binding framework will call `getComfortErrorVisibility` to get the visibility of error message. Your condition is set so that when the error message is empty or `null` the visibility is visible:

```
TextUtils.isEmpty(comfortErrorMessage.get()) ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE;
```

Because your `comfortErrorMessage` is initialized like `ObservableField()`, its initial value will be null and hence the first thing you see is a visible error field.

Maybe you should change the condition for the visibility?

Answer (score 0):

this is because you make a mistake in  `getComfortErrorVisibility` method. At start your `comfortErrorMessage` is empty so your method return visible a and text view will be shown, try change your method to:

```
@Bindable
    public int getComfortErrorVisibility(){
        return TextUtils.isEmpty(comfortErrorMessage.get()) ? View.INVISIBLE: View.VISIBLE;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HomeViewModel extends BaseObservable {

private ObservableField<String> comfortErrorMessage = new ObservableField<>();

public HomeViewModel(){
    validateSpace();
}

}
```

import text utils in your `<data>` binding tag and ...

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/error_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="@{TextUtils.isEmpty(viewmodel.comfortErrorMessage) ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your `comfortErrorVisibility` , init it as View.INVISIBLE

```
private ObservableField<String> comfortErrorMessage = new ObservableField<>();
private ObservableField<Integer> comfortErrorVisibility = new ObservableField<>(View.INVISIBLE);
```

In your XML, just put the field name:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/error_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="@{homeViewModel.comfortErrorVisibility}"/>
```

If your `comfortErrorMessage` can be changed dynamically on runtime i.e. user is able to edit it from an `EditText`, then u can instead add property changed callback

```
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.databinding.BaseObservable;
import androidx.databinding.Observable;
import androidx.databinding.ObservableField;

public class HomeViewModel extends BaseObservable {

    private ObservableField<String> comfortErrorMessage = new ObservableField<>();
    private ObservableField<Integer> comfortErrorVisibility = new ObservableField<>(View.INVISIBLE);

    public HomeViewModel() {
        validateSpace();

        comfortErrorMessage.addOnPropertyChangedCallback(
            new Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onPropertyChanged(Observable sender, int propertyId) {
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(comfortErrorMessage.get())) {
                        comfortErrorVisibility.set(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        comfortErrorVisibility.set(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    }

    private void validateSpace() {
        //some business logic to set the comfrotErrorMessage
    }
}
```

and your `comfortErrorMessage` should assigned with two-way binding with `=` sign `"@={homeViewModel.comfortErrorMessage}"`